# Is this a good use of the convolution?

Tags: experimental-physics, fourier-transform, frequency, signal-processing, noise

I would like to replicate the real response of an instrument to some signal. Here's what I have in mind: I generate some ideal signal. I then add Gaussian noise to it to produce a realistic signal s(t). For a given frequency, I know the detector's sensitivity by taking the PSD of the detector's signal over a long time period. Should I Fourier transform s(t), convolve that with the PSD and then inverse FT the result to get the noise+systematics detector response?

Comment: I suggest that you attach a block diagram with your question because this way stated it is quite ambiguous at best. Just convolving a PSD with the FT of a time signal is likely to lead to a *wrong* result, but again I am not sure what you really want. Usually, a time signal is convolved with the impulse response of the receiver filter and probably you also need the detector's nonlinear characteristic following the filter.

Comment: If you don't a good answer here in a day or so, you may want to consider posting this at [stats.se]